# ¿Cómo agrego mi diseño de teclado (layout) para que sea funcional? Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, keyboard

He creado el siguiente archivo xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:columnCount="1">
        <!-- Botones aquí -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/q"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Q" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/w"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="W" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="E" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/r"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="R" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/t"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="T" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/y"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Y" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/u"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="U" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/i"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="I" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/o"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="O" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/p"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="P" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/s"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/a"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="A" />

            <Button
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="S" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/d"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="D" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/f"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="F" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/g"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="G" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/h"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="H" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/j"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="J" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/k"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="K" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/l"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="L" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ñ"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Ñ" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/shift"
                style="@style/styleButtonIcon"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/keyboard_capslock"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
            </ImageButton>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/z"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Z" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/x"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="X" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/c"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="C" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/v"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="V" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="B" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/n"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="N" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/m"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="M" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/delete"
                style="@style/styleButtonIcon"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/backspace"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
            </ImageButton>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/numbers"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:text="\?123"
                android:textSize="13sp">
            </Button>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/comma"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=",">
            </Button>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/emoji"
                style="@style/styleButtonIcon"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/insert_emoticon"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

            </ImageButton>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/space"
                style="@style/styleButtonIcon"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:src="@drawable/space_bar"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription">
            </ImageButton>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/period"
                style="@style/styleButtonBasic"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text=".">

            </Button>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/tab"
                style="@style/styleButtonIcon"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:src="@drawable/keyboard_tab"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

            </ImageButton>

        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Donde el estilo para los botones de letras es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <style name="styleButtonBasic" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Ya he creado el servicio de método de entrada y he configurado el archivo AndroidManifest.xml, también he establecido el archivo method.xml. Pero al cambiar el método de entrada en la emulación no me aparece el diseño del teclado y me dice que la app se ha detenido.

MyInputMethodService.java:

```
package com.example.keyboard;

import android.inputmethodservice.InputMethodService;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MyInputMethodService extends InputMethodService {

    private boolean isCaps = false; // Añade esta línea

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        // Infla el diseño del teclado
        View keyboardView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_qwerty_esp, null);

        // Configura los eventos OnClickListener para cada tecla del teclado
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.q, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Q);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.w, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_W);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.e, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.r, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.t, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_T);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.y, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Y);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.u, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_U);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.i, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.o, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.p, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.a, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.s, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.d, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.f, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.g, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.h, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_H);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.j, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_J);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.k, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_K);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.l, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_L);

        Button enieButton = keyboardView.findViewById(R.id.ñ);
        enieButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
                ic.commitText("ñ", 1);
            }
        });

        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.z, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.x, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_X);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.c, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.v, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_V);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.b, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.n, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_N);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.m, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_M);

        //Signos de puntuación
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.comma, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_COMMA);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.period, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_PERIOD);
        setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(keyboardView, R.id.delete, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);

      

        Button shiftButton = keyboardView.findViewById(R.id.shift);
        shiftButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Cambia el estado de las mayúsculas
            isCaps = !isCaps;
        });

        Button delButton = keyboardView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        delButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
            if (ic != null) {
                ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            }
        });

        return keyboardView;
    }

    
    private void keyDownEvent(int keyCode) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (ic != null) {
            sendKey(ic, keyCode);
        }
    }

    // Método para enviar una tecla a la aplicación de destino
    private void sendKey(InputConnection ic, int keyCode) {
        KeyEvent downEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode);
        KeyEvent upEvent = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode);

        if (isCaps) {
            
            downEvent = new KeyEvent(downEvent.getDownTime(), downEvent.getEventTime(), downEvent.getAction(), downEvent.getKeyCode(), downEvent.getRepeatCount(), KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON);
            upEvent = new KeyEvent(upEvent.getDownTime(), upEvent.getEventTime(), upEvent.getAction(), upEvent.getKeyCode(), upEvent.getRepeatCount(), KeyEvent.META_SHIFT_ON);
        }

        ic.sendKeyEvent(downEvent);
        ic.sendKeyEvent(upEvent);
    }

    
    private void setOnClickListenerForKeyboardButton(View keyboardView, int buttonId, int keyCode) {
        Button button = keyboardView.findViewById(buttonId);
        button.setOnClickListener(v -> keyDownEvent(keyCode));
    }

}
```

method.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/subtype_es_PE"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="es_PE"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <service
            android:name=".MyInputMethodService"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Al momento de correr el código me aparecen 0 errores, aunque en el archivo del diseño del teclado se me menciona que los botones son muy pequeños, pero es que ese diseño es el que quiero utilizar. He pensado que tal vez hay un error en el manifest, pero no logro ubicarlo.